# scaffolding a controller bound to a complex model in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I have a model (**A**) consist of two other models (**B - UltrasoundDTO**   & **C - BloodTestDTO**).
When I try Adding a controller through the **MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework** option in **VS2017** it creates a controller with the corresponding views though it binds only the  properties of model A and not the properties of  **B** & **C**. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to bind the rest on my own?

[Controller creation option ][1],

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

public class CheckUpDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DayOfPeriod { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UltrasoundDTO MyUltrasoundDTO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public BloodTestDTO MyBloodTestDTO { get; set; }

  }
```

one of the methods in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,DayOfPeriod")] CheckUpDTO checkUpDTO)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(checkUpDTO);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(checkUpDTO);
        }
```

the view that corresponds to the method above:

```
@model DTOs.CheckUpDTO

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CheckUpDTO</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DayOfPeriod" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="DayOfPeriod" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DayOfPeriod" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```